# What's the recommended off camera flash setup for Canon and Sunpak flash combination?

Tags: off-camera-flash, pentax, hotshoe-flash, canon-40d

I'm new to off-camera flash photography, and [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2991/is-it-ok-to-use-different-kinds-of-strobes-together) confirmed my guess that you don't have to have off-camera flashes of the same brand; but I need a bit more info.

I've got a Canon 40D, Speedlite 430 EX II, and Sunpak auto 355AF (an old Pentax flash).

The only setup I can think of to get both flashes to fire off-camera are 2 wireless receivers (hooked up to flashes) and 1 wireless trigger (on 40D).

I'd like to hear if there are any alternatives to set these 2 flashes up off-camera; and some wireless trigger/receiver recommendations.

Comment: Are you sure that the 430EX II can be triggered by the 40D's pop-up flash? I thought it needed a line-of-sight infra-red signal from a 580EX or similar.

Comment: @Oddthinking: my bad, 40D can't trigger a flash with its built in flash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Cheap Radio Triggers

I am using triggers similar to [these](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Channel-PT-04-Wireless-Trigger-Receivers/dp/B002G90S00/ref=sr_1_14?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1298977329&sr=1-14).

They are cheap, and work very well (a few misfires / nofires, but still great for the money)

Alternatively, you can just use a sync cable for the sunpak and leave the 430 on slave.  (Check that the sunpack is low voltage first - i.e. it's safe to attach it directly to your camera).

#### Edit

link to a similar product (the old link is 404):
[4-channel radio triggers on amazon.co.uk](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B001MP8KKE/ref=oh_details_o00_s00_i02)

Comment: Could you name the device, because the link just returns a 404 error.

Comment: @MiljenkoBarbir, I've added another link.